# "The enrapturing discoveries of our field systematically conceal (...) the analogical train of thought that is the authentic life of mathematics..."

Tags: soft-question, philosophy

In the preface of the book *Discrete Thoughts*, Gian-Carlo Rota writes:

> Sometime, in a future that is knocking at our door, we shall have to retrain ourselves or our children to properly tell the truth. The exercise will be particularly painful in mathematics. The enrapturing discoveries of our field systematically conceal, like footprints erased in the sand, the analogical train of thought that is the authentic life of mathematics. Shocking as it may be to a conservative logician, the day will come when currently vague concepts such as motivation and purpose will be made formal and accepted as constituents of a revamped logic, where they will at last be allotted the equal status they deserve, side by side with axioms and theorems. Until that day, however, the truths of mathematics will make only fleeting appearances, like shameful confessions whispered to a priest, to a psychiatrist,
>   or to a wife.

I am unable to decipher the poetry here: what could he possibly mean by this?

Comment: Why do you think that a "great" mathematician says **always** "great" truth in every field in which he is interested ? Isaac Newton spent number of years and writed thousand of pages (in manuscript) on two subjects which interested him much more than *gravitation* : alchemy and biblical chronology (i.e.to date with precision the year of Noah's flood). Rota's philosophical work was influenced by the *phenomenology* of Edmund Husserl; assuming that his philosophical thinkung is relevant (I do not know) I think you have to master Husserl's "language" in order to understand it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What makes you think that I think this: "Why do you think that a "great" mathematician says always "great" truth in every field in which he is interested ?"? I also don't think the comment I quoted above has anything to do with ("esoteric") philosophy in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Clearly", in his "oracolar" Preface, Rota is alluding to an *inner life* of mathematical thinking, where *meaning* lies.

The mainstream "logician" (???) form of mathematics, shaped into "still-life" collections of axioms and theorems is deprived of *meaning*.

I think that, in order to appreciate Rota's thinking, we need to practice with [Edmund Husserl](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/husserl/)'s [Phenomenology](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/phenomenology/) and its [theory of meaning](http://www.iep.utm.edu/huss-int/).

According to me, there is clearly a place for *meaning*, *intuition* and *creativity* in mathematical thinking.

**Personally** I do **not** think that *symbolic* thinking in mathematics is deprived of meaning and I see no contradiction between symbolism and formalization, form one side, and intuition and creativity, from the other side.

As a silly example, try to read Sixteenth-century algebraist (like Cardano and Tartaglia) descriptions of method for the solution of third degree equations [see John Fauvel & Jeremy Gray (editors), [The History of Mathematics : A Reader](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0333427912) (1987), page 257] :

> Find me two numbers such that when they are added together, they make as much
> as the cube of the lesser added to the product of its triple with the square of the greater; and the cube of the greater added to its triple times the square of the lesser makes 64 more than the sum of these two numbers. [i.e., find $a, b$ such that $a + b = b^3 + 3ba^2$ and $a^3 + 3ab^2 = 64 + a + b$.]

Compare now with modern algebra, and - I think - you can appreciate the enormous *creativity* effort made in the following century by Descartes and Newton and Leibniz to *invent* a symbolism so powerful which disclosed completely new fields of mathematical inquiry and thinking.

I prefer an approach to the problem of meaning and intuition in mathematics through the so-called *Analytical Philosophy* tradition; see :

> - Michael Dummett, [Origins of Analytical Philosophy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0674644735) (1996)
> - Claire Ortiz Hill & Guillermo E.Rosado Haddock, [Husserl or Frege? Meaning, Objectivity, and Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0812694171) (2000)
> - Richard Tieszen, [After Gödel : Platonism and Rationalism in Mathematics and Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019960620X) (2011)
> - Charles Parsons, [From Kant to Husserl : Selected Essays](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0674048539) (2012).

Comment: I am not convinced that Rota is making an argument against symbolism and formalism (which I am a fan of too!), since I have long since been a disciple of E.W.Dijkstra-beyond-the-grave.

Comment: @user89 - See page 154 : "We often hear that mathematics consists mainly in "proving theorems." Is a writer's job mainly that of"writing sentences"? A mathematician's work is mostly a tangle of guesswork, analogy, wishful thinking and frustration, and proof, far from being the core of discovery, is more often than not a way of making sure that our minds are not playing tricks. [...] To master mathematics is to master an intangible view, it is to acquire the skill of the virtuoso who cannot pin his performance on criteria."

Comment: I see what you mean now. I would especially disagree with this part: "...proof, far from being the core of discovery, is more often than not a way of making sure that our minds are not playing tricks", as formalism can allow us to clear the fog and see new roads which otherwise would have been difficult to see. Now, I wonder if Rota is referring to "proof" in that dry and delapidated sense of "proof" often encountered in textbooks: which are meant to confuse the reader rather than elucidate a concept (what E.W.Dijkstra would have called "pulling rabbits out of a hat"), and are often the...

Comment: ...consequence of the author himself not knowing the underlying motivations behind the subject?

Comment: Also, thinking about it a bit more...I do not see why analogies are important in developing mathematics. If anything, I can more clearly see why analogies play a strong role in crippling the imagination...

Comment: Although, perhaps Rota means that in order to understand how one subject develops from another, and what motivated the various details within it, one must be aware of the "analogical train of thought" present due to the development being conducted by human beings, who are thus naturally affected by their past experiences?

Comment: @user89 - of courese, in order to understand "motivation" behind discovery of new axioms/theories/proofs it is necessary to study hsitorical context and also "human" context (philosophical ideas, etc); I agrre with this. I do not know if Rota's essays deal with some examples ...

Answer (score 2):

The author is describing a problem that I am extremely familiar with, and in fact so are all mathematics students whether they know it or not: mathematicians apparently don't consider it's worth it to think about how their subject was developed.

Well, that's an unfair generalization, I've had several professors that do make the effort, and I could cite several textbooks from my own shelves that contain passages lamenting the very same issue. But I've also seen many textbooks, and certain classes, which start, on page 1 chapter 1, with the words "Definition 1.1" and then proceed as though written by a robot to vomit forth pages and pages of definitions and theorems, while the reader can only scratch their head and wonder the point of any of them are.

This is a problem in education, however, and I'm not sure that's what the author is talking about, but I would think it's something related (given that in the next sentence he immediately mentions "motivation" and "purpose").

Answer (score 1):

I think that Gian-Carlo Rota is making two very specific claims; that these claims are wrong; and that nonetheless, they're still *relevant*.

**The first thing I think he's saying:**

- Mathematics does not (currently) have a formalism to encode why we actually *care* about particular formal systems, and this is a problem.

Why I think its wrong:

- We give *semantics* for formal systems in order to explain why we care about them.

Why it is still relevant:

- You sometimes read papers that present formal systems, but give no semantics; and, therefore, no motivation. Such a paper is necessarily badly written, and needs revision.

**The second thing I think he's saying:**

- Mathematics does not have a formalism to encode *how* we're actually thinking about something.

Why I think its wrong:

- Structuralist mathematics is all *about* how we're thinking about things; its all about translating between perspectives.

Why it is still relevant:

- Structuralism still hasn't made significant inroads into our ways of talking; e.g. we still talk about Abelian groups as if they're particular kinds of groups, rather than objects of the category $\mathbf{Ab}$ which is canonically equipped with a forgetful functor $\mathbf{Ab} \rightarrow \mathbf{Grp}$. So the "painful retraining of ourselves and our children" that he speaks of is very much going on at the moment.

Comment: Could you provide some clarification on what you mean by "semantics"? (Sorry, just a student here :/)

Comment: @user89, unfortunately semantics is kind of hard to explain. But basically it is an assignment of concrete entities to the (otherwise meaningless) strings of a formal system. [Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_%28logic%29) a wikipedia page to get you started, though.

Answer (score 1):

Rota's ideas on the "analogical train of thought" that is the life of mathematics have been developed (rather satisfactorily in my opinion) by Grattan-Guinness in his essay

Grattan-Guinness, Ivor
Solving Wigner's mystery: the reasonable (though perhaps limited) effectiveness of mathematics in the natural sciences. 
Math. Intelligencer  30  (2008),  no. 3, 7–17. 
See [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2437195).

Grattan-Guinness's article challenges the received view that there is something mysterious about the applicability of mathematics, and also describes some mechanisms by which the process of discovery in mathematics operates. A central place is given to reasoning by analogy from related or not-so-related fields. His article is very broad and covers many fields of mathematics and applications. A true gem that only an experienced historian of mathematics and natural science could have written.

Comment: Could you include a few sentences in your post describing why this article is particularly relevant?